# Determinar tipo de triángulo

Tags: c#, clase

Necesito corregir mi formulario con clases y métodos que me determina que tipo de triangulo es, dado sus tres lados

**clase y metodo**

```
namespace ejercicio3 {
 public class Tipo { // private String respuesta;
  private Double l1;
  private Double l2;
  private Double l3;
  private Boolean respuesta;


  public Double L1 {
   get;
   set;
  }
  public Double L2 {
   get;
   set;
  }
  public Double L3 {
   get;
   set;
  }
  public Boolean Respuesta {
   get;
   set;
  }

  public bool Verificacion(bool si, string no) {
   if (l1 + l2 > l3)
    return true;
   else {
    return false;
   }

  }
 }
}
```

**Llamado `bntcalcular`**

Instancio la clase pero no me retorna ningun valor

```
public partial class frmTipos_deTriangulos: Form {
 TiposdeTriangulos MiTiposdeTriangulos = new TiposdeTriangulos();

 public frmTipos_deTriangulos() {
  InitializeComponent();
 }

 private void btnvalidar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  if (L1 + L2 >= L3 && L2 + L3 >= l1 && l3 + l1 >= l2) {
   if (l1 == l2 && l2 == l3) {
    MessageBox.Show("El Triangulo Es Equilatero");
    return 0;
   }
   if (l1 == l2 || l1 == l3 || l2 == l3) {
    MessageBox.Show("El Triangulo Es Isoseles");
    return 0;
   }
   if (l1 != l2 || l1 != l3 || l3 != l2) {
    MessageBox.Show("El Triangulo es Escaleno");
    return 0;
   }
  } else {
   MessageBox.Show("Los Datos introducidos no pertenecen a un Triangulo");
   return 0;
  }
  return 0;
  MiTiposdeTriangulos.L1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtlado1.Text);
  MiTiposdeTriangulos.L2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtlado2.Text);
  MiTiposdeTriangulos.L3 = Convert.ToInt32(txtlado3.Text); 

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haces algunas cosas un poco raras, como llamar a las variables L1, L2, L3 y luego utilizas l1, l2 o l3. También generas una clase Tipo donde guardas las longitudes de los triángulos pero no se ve que la utilices. Además, no te devuelve nada porque no haces bien la comparación, mira mi primer if. Voy a intentar solucionarlo tocando el menor código posible con lo que tienes.

```
namespace ejercicio3 {
    public class Tipo {
    private double l1 {get; set;} //Creo variables tipo double y no objetos tipo Double
    private double l2 {get; set;}
    private double l3 {get; get;}
    private bool respuesta {get; set;} //Creo variable tipo bool y no objetos tipo Boolean

    public bool Verificacion(bool si, string no) {
        if (l1 + l2 > l3)
            return true;
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }
}

public partial class frmTipos_deTriangulos: Form {
    Tipo t = new Tipo();  //Creamos el objeto tipo Tipo
    t.L1 = 1;             //Le doy valor a los lados, se puede hacer pidiéndolos por teclado
    t.L2 = 1;
    t.L3 = 1;

    private void btnvalidar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        if (t.L1 + t.L2 >= t.L3 && t.L2 + t.L3 >= t.L1 && t.L3 + t.L1 >= t.L2) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Los Datos introducidos no pertenecen a un Triangulo");
        }else{
            if (t.L1 == t.L2 && t.L2 == t.L3) {
                MessageBox.Show("El Triangulo Es Equilatero");
                return 0;
            }
            if (t.L1 == t.L2 || t.L1 == t.L3 || t.L2 == t.L3) {
                MessageBox.Show("El Triangulo Es Isoseles");
                return 0;
            }
            if (t.L1 != t.L2 || t.L1 != t.L3 || t.L3 != t.L2) {
                MessageBox.Show("El Triangulo es Escaleno");
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: el num en que parte lo debo agregar para darle solución

Comment: No entiendo lo que preguntas, que num?

Answer (score 1):

Tienes el código bastante liado.
Creas una clase `Tipo` que no utilizas. Luego creas una instancia de `TiposdeTriangulos` a la que asignas valores pero no utilizas para nada.

A la hora de definir tus clases lo primero que debes pensar es qué entidades o conceptos diferentes tienes. En tu caso serían claramente dos: Triángulos (cada triángulo que defines con la longitud de sus lados) y Tipos de Triángulos (que puede ser Equilátero, Isósceles o Escaleno)

Para los Tipos de Triángulos podría bastarte con crearte una enumeración `TipoTriangulo`:

```
public enum TipoTriangulo
{
    Equilatero,
    Isosceles,
    Escaleno
}
```

Para definir la clase `Triangulo` en la que puedes establecer la longitud de los lados del triángulo y crear un método `Verificacion` que devuelva el tipo de triángulo definido podrías crear 3 propiedades de sólo lectura para la longitud de los lados y establecer los valores siempre desde el constructor. De esta forma puedes realizar la comprobación de que los valores de la longitud de los lados es correcta en el propio constructor:

```
    public Triangulo(double l1, double l2, double l3)
    {
        // Comprobacón de valores
        if (l1 <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(l1));
        if (l2 <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(l2));
        if (l3 <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(l3));
        if (l1 + l2 < l3 || l2 + l3 < l1 || l3 + l1 < l2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"Valores no válidos para formar un triángulo: {l1} {l2} {l3}");
        }

        L1 = l1;
        L2 = l2;
        L3 = l3;
    }

    public Double L1 { get; }
    public Double L2 { get; }
    public Double L3 { get; }

}
```

Como puedes ver en el constructor compruebo que la longitud de los lados es mayor que 0 y que se puede construir con ellos un triángulo. Si no es así se lanza una excepción indicando que los valores proporcionados no son válidos.

El método `Verificacion` debería comprobar la longitud de los lados y devolver el valor `TipoTriangulo` correcto:

```
    public TipoTriangulo Verificacion()
    {
        if (L1 == L2 && L1 == L3)
        {
            return TipoTriangulo.Equilatero;
        }
        if (L1 == L2 || L1 == L3 || L2 == L3)
        {
            return TipoTriangulo.Isosceles;
        }
        return TipoTriangulo.Escaleno;
    }
```

De esta forma el código de la clase completa quedaría como:

```
public class Triangulo
{
    public Triangulo(double l1, double l2, double l3)
    {
        // Comprobacón de valores
        if (l1 <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(l1));
        if (l2 <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(l2));
        if (l3 <= 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(l3));
        if (l1 + l2 < l3 || l2 + l3 < l1 || l3 + l1 < l2)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException(
                $"Valores no válidos para formar un triángulo: {l1} {l2} {l3}");
        }

        L1 = l1;
        L2 = l2;
        L3 = l3;
    }

    public Double L1 { get; }
    public Double L2 { get; }
    public Double L3 { get; }

    public TipoTriangulo Verificacion()
    {
        if (L1 == L2 && L1 == L3)
        {
            return TipoTriangulo.Equilatero;
        }
        if (L1 == L2 || L1 == L3 || L2 == L3)
        {
            return TipoTriangulo.Isosceles;
        }
        return TipoTriangulo.Escaleno;
    }

}
```

Ahora en el formulario al hacer click en el botón `btnvalidar` simplemente deberías convertir los valores de los textbox a números, crear la instancia de `Triangulo` y llamar al método `Verificacion` para obtener el tipo de triángulo:

```
public partial class frmTipos_deTriangulos : Form
{
    public frmTipos_deTriangulos()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnvalidar_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double l1, l2, l3;
        if (!double.TryParse(txtlado1.Text, out l1))
        {
            MessageBox.Show($@"Valor no válido para lado 1: {txtlado1.Text}");
            return;
        }
        if (!double.TryParse(txtlado2.Text, out l2))
        {
            MessageBox.Show($@"Valor no válido para lado 2: {txtlado2.Text}");
            return;
        }
        if (!double.TryParse(txtlado3.Text, out l3))
        {
            MessageBox.Show($@"Valor no válido para lado 3: {txtlado3.Text}");
            return;
        }

        // Creamos el triángulo
        var miTriangulo = new Triangulo(l1, l2, l3);
        // Recuperamos el tipo
        var tipoTriangulo = miTriangulo.Verificacion();
        MessageBox.Show($@"El triángulo es {tipoTriangulo}. Lados {miTriangulo.L1} {miTriangulo.L2} {miTriangulo.L3}");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Estimado te envío una solución
la clase Tipo actualizarla a lo siguiente:

```
namespace Demo01
{
    public class Tipo
    {
        public Double L1 { get; set; }
        public Double L2 { get; set; }
        public Double L3 { get; set; }

        public String TipoTriangulo()
        {
            if (L1 + L2 >= L3 && L2 + L3 >= L1 && L3 + L1 >= L2)
            {
                if (L1 == L2 && L2 == L3)
                    return "El Triangulo Es Equilatero";
                if (L1 == L2 || L1 == L3 || L2 == L3)
                    return "El Triangulo Es Isoseles";
                else
                    return "El Triangulo es Escaleno";
            }
            else
                return "Los Datos introducidos no pertenecen a un Triangulo";
        }
    }
}
```

En el Formulario utiliza este codigo

```
namespace Demo01
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Tipo MiTiposdeTriangulos = new Tipo();
            MiTiposdeTriangulos.L1 = Convert.ToInt32(txtlado1.Text);
            MiTiposdeTriangulos.L2 = Convert.ToInt32(txtlado2.Text);
            MiTiposdeTriangulos.L3 = Convert.ToInt32(txtlado3.Text);

            MessageBox.Show(MiTiposdeTriangulos.TipoTriangulo());

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ya realice lo solicitado pero cuando lo ejecuto el formulario no me muestra ningún mensaje

Comment: Amigo, preocupas pues si no puedes copiar y pegar este código en tu aplicacion debes revisar un poco como crear una aplicacion en Visual Studio. Por favor si puedes dime que errores te muestran o si necesitas algunas imagenes o la aplicacion completa.